# ios Bug fix works locally but isn't working live

Tags: ios

I worked on some bugs for an app and the fixes seemed to work fine on the simulators and physical devices I tested them on. Now that the update has gone live though, I have reports from users saying the same bugs still exist. I downloaded the app from the app store instead of loading it from xcode and indeed the bugs are still there. Has anyone one else ran into this issue? If so do you have any idea if it is a problem with xcode, ios, the app store, or something else?

EDIT:

I've done some more looking around about '.ipa'. Is it possible that the live '.ipa' is different from the one that was submitted?

Comment: Are you sure you submitted the right version of the app to Apple?

Comment: Yep, it was saved to a git server and tested locally by someone other than myself before being submitted.

Comment: check the file size of the previous buggy `.ipa` and new bug-fix `.ipa` & you just might be able to identify whether you uploaded the bug-fix version or mistakenly a still buggy version

Comment: Try and submit it again making absolutely sure it's the right version. Make sure you're on the right git branch ... ?

Comment: What exactly is the bug?

Comment: The original bugs had to do with table cells not resizing correctly to their content and indexing wrong. The current issue is that the bug fixes seem to work fine on the simulator and on devices that load the code from Xcode but don't work when downloaded from the live update or the app store.